# Prediction interval for OLS with non-normally distributed residuals

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, normality-assumption, prediction-interval, quantiles

I'm estimating a multiple linear regression model (found in equation 19 of "The volatility of realized volatility", Corsi et al. https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/25467/1/515328057.PDF) using ordinary least squares, and find that the residuals aren't normally distributed but exhibit skewness and excess kurtosis, which is well approximated by a normal inverse Gaussian distribution. Is it possible to calculate prediction intervals in this case? In the normal case the quantile $q$ for the new observation is given by

$y(q) = \hat{y} + se\times ppf_{t}(q)$

with $ppf_t$ the percent point function of the $t$ distribution. Is it possible in the non-normal case to use a similar formula but involving the percent point function of the residual distribution; i.e.,

$y(q) = \hat{y} + se\times ppf_{NIG}(q)$

for the normal inverse Gaussian distribution, or is there some other parametric/non-parametric method for calculating prediction intervals in this case (e.g., a multivariate extension of quantile regression)?

Comment: What do you mean by a multivariate extension of quantile regression? What you’re doing appears to involve a univariate response variable.

Comment: Apologies, what I mean is that I have a univariate response variable and 3 independent variables ($y = ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3$).

Comment: This seems like an appropriate time for quantile regression. What would be inadequate about such an approach?